# spark elasticsearch: Multiple ES-Hadoop versions detected in the classpath

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, elasticsearch, spark-submit

I'm new to spark. I'm trying to run a spark job that loads data to elasticsearch. I've built a fat jar from my code and used it during `spark-submit`.

```
spark-submit \
  --class CLASS_NAME \
  --master yarn \
  --deploy-mode cluster \
  --num-executors 20 \
  --executor-cores 5 \
  --executor-memory 32G \
  --jars EXTERNAL_JAR_FILES \
  PATH_TO_FAT_JAR
```

The maven dependency of `elasticsearch-hadoop` dependency is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch-hadoop</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.10</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

When I don't include the `elasticsearch-hadoop` jar file in the `EXTERNAL_JAR_FILES` list, then I'm getting this error.

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.CompatUtils
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
  at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:344)
  at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.util.ObjectUtils.loadClass(ObjectUtils.java:73)
  ... 26 more
```

If I include it in the `EXTERNAL_JAR_FILES` list, I'm getting this error.

```
java.lang.Error: Multiple ES-Hadoop versions detected in the classpath; please use only one
jar:file:PATH_TO_CONTAINER/__app__.jar
jar:file:PATH_TO_CONTAINER/elasticsearch-hadoop-5.6.10.jar

  at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.util.Version.<clinit>(Version.java:73)
  at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestService.createWriter(RestService.java:572)
  at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsRDDWriter.write(EsRDDWriter.scala:58)
  at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.EsSparkSQL$$anonfun$saveToEs$1.apply(EsSparkSQL.scala:97)
  at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.EsSparkSQL$$anonfun$saveToEs$1.apply(EsSparkSQL.scala:97)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Is there anything that needs to be done to overcome it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved by not including the `elasticserach-hadoop` jar in the fat jar I've built. I've mentioned `scope` param to `provided` in the dependency.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-hadoop</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.10</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

### I solved this problem

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-hadoop</artifactId>
        <version>7.4.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

note that `[<scope>provided</scope>]`

then you can use command:

```
bin/spark-submit \
--maste local[*] \
--class xxxxx  \
--jars https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-hadoop/7.4.2/elasticsearch-hadoop-7.4.2.jar \
/your/path/xxxx.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue because I changed my project's build from SBT to POM. On exploring. I saw that there were two jars in classpath one from .ivy2 folder another from .mvn
I deleted the one from .ivy2 and the issue disappeared. Hope it helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I had a dependency that used a different version of elasticsearch-spark than the elasticsearch-spark dependency explicitly stated in my pom file. For example, I added the elasticsearch-spark-30_2.12 dependency but I had a separate dependency that used elasticsearch-spark-13_2.10 so I just added an exclusion to that separate dependency in my pom file like so,

```
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-spark-13_2.10</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```